# Remove deleted orders from Magento sales > orders

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've tried a few different methods for deleting test orders from Magento.

1. Using a plugin(http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/asperience-deleteorders.html)
2. SQL commands found in a forum post(http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1680/P420/)
3. SQL commands given to me by Enterprise support
4. a PHP script found here at stack overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526914/how-can-i-delete-test-order-from-magento)

Some if not all of these methods seem to delete the entries from the database however none of these solutions remove the order from the back end of Magento. These orders are still showing under Sales > Orders as well as the dashboard. We have a development environment, a testing environment and a production environment however we still like to place test orders in production to ensure our changes were pushed correctly.

Am I missing something? Others seem to be satisfied with the Plugin/SQL/PHP deletion methods listed above. I've tried flushing the cache and cache storage. Nothing seems to work. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Modern version of Magento propagate order information to the `sales_flat_order_grid` table, and it's this table the admin console reads from when displaying orders for the grid. I didn't look at the methods you linked to, but my guess is they don't clear out this table.

Answer (score 0):

In fresh install, http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/asperience-deleteorders.html works perfectly as there are constraint between sales table and sales_grid table. New versions of http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/asperience-deleteorders.html detects if specific deletion of sales_grid must be done